# Setting tagName on application template in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Views are deprecated in ember js.  I want to set the tagName for the application template to "empty" because I don't want my content wrapped in a div - it messes up my css.  Previously I have don this by creating an views/application.js and setting `tagName: ''` but views are deprecated - how can I do this without views?

Comment: Don't you think empty tagName for application template is also deprecated/not encouraged? Without using private properties I doubt you can do it again.

Comment: instead of views, are you using components now? if so here's the tagName doc for components: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/

Comment: I know about components. But I am not talking about a component. I am specifically talking about the application template.  I don't want <body> <div class="ember-view">.  It messes up my css

Comment: I think it's not the right thing to dislodge the application's root DOM-element. Ember needs it for handling all native events, after all.

Comment: Exactly how does/could a div mess up your CSS? Probably fixing your CSS is the quickest fix.

Comment: I am using an of-the-shelf theme and I don't want to mess with it.  My question is "how to" get rid of the div not "should I" ;-) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with the comments that this may not be something you want to do, you can use the [ember-legacy-views](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-legacy-views) addon until routable components are released.

Tagless components are also mentioned in the [Component Unification](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/angle-bracket-components/active/0000-component-unification.md) RFC, which you might find interesting.

Comment: this seems like the way to go.  I got a similar answer at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12183

Answer (score 0):

[[Reposting from this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736211/ember-application-template-classname)]

You can control the top-level tag (even not rendering it), and its CSS classes by modifying your Ember Application as follows:

```
// app/app.js

App = Ember.Application.extend({
  ApplicationView: Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['my-custom-classname'],
    // Or to omit the tag entirely:
    tagName: '',
  }),
  // ...
});
```

As seen in [this discussion](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-do-i-add-classnames-to-the-first-element-of-the-page-without-using-a-view/8205/7).

This does not require any hacks or a legacy plugin.