# How to set the class of the root div in an Ember application?

Tags: ember.js

I have an **Ember 2.3.0** application. When the application is initialized, Ember creates a root `div` inside which, everything I create is inserted. This `div` looks like this:

```
<div id="ember351" class="ember-view"></div>
```

This element is a **first child** of the `<body>` element. I need to be able to set the class of this `div`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you don't need the `class` inside the `div`, but you can access the `div` from *CSS* or *JavaScript*.

You can access that `div` via *CSS* like this

```
body > .ember-view
```

Or via *JavaScript* like this

```
document.querySelector('body > .ember-view')
```

---

**UPDATE** In Ember it would be something like this.

Use the  `init` hook in the application controller in combination with the [`Ember.run.next` function](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_next).

```
// application/controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';
const {
  Controller,
  run { next }
} = Ember;

export defaultController.extend({  
  addClass() => {
    next(this, function() {
      document.querySelector('body > .ember-view').className += " your-class";
    })
  }.on('init')
});
```

Here is a [demo in ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d9ccb2ca4ad16add3e0c?numColumns=2).

Comment: Where would I trigger the JavaScript? Right now, I am doing something similar but I'm using a $(document).ready() inside a component. Is there a better way?

Comment: Updated the answer to explain how to use it in Ember.

Comment: I believe this answer is wrong. `didInsertElement` is a method hook in Components, not Routes. It is also generally a bad practice in Ember to mutate the DOM manually instead of relying on bindings.

Comment: @locks, you made the `didInsertElement` a *function*, it should be a *key* in the *object* of the *controller*. You are right about the *route*, it should be *controller*, but the `didInsertElement` seems deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you can't with vanilla Ember.js 2.3. You would need to install the `ember-legacy-views` and then customize the application view as shown in [Customizing a View's Element](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/views/customizing-a-views-element/).

Answer (score 0):

Create views/application.js file with the following content,

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['myclassname']
});
```

not sure though what the side-effects of using a component as a view may be

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the question using a selector such as `body > .ember-view` works fine in development, but that **will not work** if your life, er, tests depend on it, since Ember mounts the app to the page differently in test environment.

Instead of...

```
<body>
  <div class="ember-view">
    <!-- app -->
  </div>
</body>
```

... it mounts as...

```
<body>
  <div id="ember-testing-container">
    <div id="ember-testing">
      <div class="ember-view">
        <!-- app -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This might not be an issue for most people, but for me it was - I was attaching a plugin to the root app selected via `body > .ember-view`, which didn't work.

I was able to use `.ember-view:eq(0)` instead, which grabs the first `.ember-view` on the page - the app.

Answer (score 0):

In Ember 2.7 and below you can control the top-level tag (even not rendering it), and its CSS classes by modifying your Ember Application as follows:

```
// app/app.js

App = Ember.Application.extend({
  ApplicationView: Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['my-custom-classname'],
    // Or to omit the tag entirely:
    tagName: '',
  }),
});
```

As seen in [this discussion](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-do-i-add-classnames-to-the-first-element-of-the-page-without-using-a-view/8205/7), and as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736211/ember-application-template-classname/43326203).